# C++ Read Input from Console Row by Row for Magic Square Checker

Tags: c++

I'm working towards creating a application which asks for size, input of a square (row by row), check if the square is a magic square or not.

My instructor requires the data to be read row by row. I'm not sure where I messed it up. The function only reads rowNumber-1 iteration and it assigned magicSquare with different number from the input.

```
void Magic_Square::read_data(){
    char line[100];
    for(int i=0; i<rowNumber; i++){
        cin.getline(line,100, ' ');
        magicSquare.push_back(vector<int>());
        for(int j=0; j<rowNumber;j++){
            magicSquare[i].push_back((int)line[j]);
        }
   }
}
```

Edit: I found solution which was way simpler as I overcomplicated the problem. Here is the code:

```
void Magic_Square::read_data(){
    int a;
    for (int i=0; i<rowNumber; i++){
        magicSquare.push_back(vector<int>());
        for (int j=0; j<rowNumber; j++){
            cin>>a;
            magicSquare[i].push_back(a);
        }
    }
}
```

The solution @Fureeish provided also works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Well, now that the code has fundamentally changed from your initial post, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46159095/edit) to include the input data verbatim, and include the mechanism for how you acquire the mysterious value `rowNumber`. (and the cast to `int` from `char` is still near-certainly wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `magicSquare` is of a type `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, let's take a look at your code.

First of all, I would encourage you to use `std::string` instead of `char[]` not only for simplicity, but also for safety reasons.

Secondly, I cannot deduce from where the `rowNumber` comes from, but I assume that it is a member variable of your `Magic_suqre` class.

**EDIT**: Previous version of this answer was wrong since it was unclear in what way the input is being provided.

Now that we know everything, we can start from the beginning. Since we are dealing with numbers provided in a line separated by whitespace, we can use `std::stringstream` to extract them. *Remember to add `#include <sstream>` and `#include <string>`*.

```
void Magic_Square::read_data()
{
    std::string line;
    for(int i=0; i<rowNumber; i++){
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        magicSquare.push_back(std::vector<int>());
        int tmp = 0;
        std::istringstream ss(line); // create a stringstream using line
        while(ss >> tmp) magicSquare[i].push_back(tmp);
        // for reach number in the line, put it into a newly added vector
    }
}
```

To briefly explain how the code works - after you scan your input line and emplace a new row by calling `magicSquare.push_back(std::vector<int>())`, we create an instance of `std::istringstream` containing the scanned `line`. In the loop, we extract every number using `operator >>` and `push_back()` that number to your newly added vector.

Comment: When I entered 1 2 3 to check, the output are 1 -16 2 (I guess I have to work on converting it to int.) However, if the inputs are 12 1 3 (since there is possiblility for inputs to be a 2 digit integer), the out are respectively 1 3 -16. I assume that the code push_back(line[j] -'0') only pushes back whatever integer it encounters regardless of ' ' or digit after it.

Comment: This is the problem of providing an input. My initial understanding was that you enter `123` and expect them to be three, independent digits. Now I see that you expect the input numbers to be divided by a whitespace. Let me edit the answer respectively in a second

Comment: @HallieTruong and yes, you are right that "*`push_back(line[j] -'0')` only pushes back whatever integer it encounters regardless of ' ' or digit after it*". The `' '` character is also represented as a number, thus it can be converted to `int`. Pushing back that number, however, is not desired. See the edit for working example